# Counting number of non-referenced rows in a table

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, left-join, query-performance

I have a table `addresses` and many tables that has a `address_id` column that references an address (all have foreign key contraints). I want to find the number of addresses that are not referenced from any of the other tables.

I've tried the following query, but it is VERY slow:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM addresses A
LEFT JOIN customers C ON C.address_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN agreements AG ON AG.address_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN products P ON P.address_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN letters L ON L.address_id = A.id
WHERE C.id IS NULL
AND AG.id IS NULL
AND P.id IS NULL
AND L.id IS NULL
```

Is there any way I can do this, without the query taking forever?

Comment: every optimation question needs 2 things an EXPLAIN for the query and all the create tables for all tables involved

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by rewriting this with `not exists`:

```
select count(*)
from addresses a
where 
        not exists (select 1 from customers c  where c.address_id = a.id)
    and not exists (select 1 from agreements g where g.address_id = a.id)
    and not exists (select 1 from products p   where p.address_id = a.id)
    and not exists (select 1 from letters l    where l.address_id = a.id)
```

Then, make sure to have the following indexes in place to speed up the query:

```
customers(address_id)
agreements(address_id)
products(address_id)
letters(address_id)
```

If you have properly defined the `address_id` columns as foreign keys to `address(id)`, then these indexes are already there.